# renaming same named layout xml files in different layout folders

Tags: xml, layout, renaming

I've recently come across an issue in eclipse, whenever I copy an xml file from `res/layout` folder to any other layout folder e.g. `res/layout-sw320dp`, `res/layout-sw480dp` or `res/layout-sw600dp` etc then after that renaming any of them causes all the files (which are of same names but in different layout folders as per Android documentation) to be renamed...

Why is this? The only solution that seems to be working is to make another layout xml file in the corresponding layout folder and then copy the contents from the source file rather than copying the entire file.  Can anybody please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

That maybe because Eclipse was designed that way. It knows that usually programmer would want the same layout to work ion devices of all screen densities so it automatically copies the same layout XML file.